# Digital Humanities Quarterly bibliography style in REVTeX

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I need to produce a bibliography in keeping with the [Digital Humanities Quarterly (DHQ) style guidelines](http://digitalhumanities.org:8081/dhq/submissions/textGuidelines.html) using version 4.1r of REVTeX. Here is an example of a correctly formatted bibliographic entry:

> [Bansal 2015] Bansal, M. K. and Jain, R. “Application of generalized differential transform method to fractional relaxation oscillation equation”, Antarctica Journal of Mathematics, 12 (2015): 85-95.

I got so far as being able to produce the following format:

> M. K. Bansal and R. Jain, Antarctica Journal of Mathematics 12, 5 (2015).

Here is the tex file:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\setcitestyle{authoryear, round}

\begin{document}
    A token citation:~\citep{Bansal2015}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Here is the corresponding references.bib file:

```
@Article{Bansal2015,
    author = {Manish Kumar Bansal and Rashmi Jain},
    journal = {Antarctica Journal of Mathematics},
    title = {Application of generalized differential transform method to fractional relaxation oscillation equation},
    year = {2015},
    volume = {12},
    pages = {85-95},
}
```

Any assistance in producing the DHQ style would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and use a [customized bibtex style](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib), instead of using the apsrev4-1 style. This will allow you to have the format you wish. I actually tried to make something similar to what you want.

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\bibliographystyle{dhqnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\begin{document}

\citep{bansal2015application}

\bibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}
```

with the following bibfile.bib in the same folder:

```
@article{bansal2015application,
  title={Application of generalized differential transform method to fractional-order Ricatti€Ž differential equation and numerical result},
  author={Bansal, MK and Jain, R},
  journal={International Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics},
  volume={99},
  number={3},
  pages={355--366},
  year={2015}
}
```

And the dhqnat.bst file, also in the same folder. This last file can be found in [here](https://github.com/felipeortg/custom-bib/blob/master/dhqnat.bst).

The result was:
[image]
Which to me seems pretty close to what you asked.